# Is there a notion of a smooth point on a surface?

Tags: calculus, measure-theory, differential-geometry

I know that an entire surface can be smooth, but can a single point on a surface be considered smooth? Even if there is no smooth neighborhood about that point?

If so, can you say that a surface is smooth iff all the points on the surface are smooth? Is there a notion of almost everywhere smooth?

Comment: Nope.  A point cannot be smooth.

Comment: In algebraic geometry maybe.

Comment: Not just in algebraic geometry. If the surface is a manifold, every point is smooth. But what about the origin in the cone $x^2+y^2=z^2$? This is a point at which the surface is *not* smooth.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin
This is the opposite of what OP is asking about.

Comment: You’re right. I missed the key sentence. If a surface is smooth at a point, then it must be smooth in a neighborhood of that point — if the rank of the derivative of the defining function is maximal at $P$, then it is maximal nearby. This follows from continuity of the determinant.